# Is there a way to create creeping line without flickering?

Tags: javascript, scripting, browser, marquee

I've tried javascript (w. jQuery), flash, canvas, but i cannot get rid of flickering, even on fast browsers (Chrome).

[Javascript example](http://jsbin.com/emayi4)

Most of time it does go smooth, but if you'll watch it for a while you'll see that it lags periodically. Seems strange that it's too hard for browser to render an animated line of text.

Comment: It's hard on the eyes regardless of whether it flickers or not. Maybe larger text/images and slower motion will solve both of those problems.

Comment: Using `1px` decrements and halving the interval time stops it flickering for me, at least.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you (if at all) against using `<marquee>`?

Comment: Also, specifying `move` instead of `"move()"` should be a tiny bit quicker.

Comment: @Brad Christie: `<marquee>` looks even worse...

Comment: Is it actually flickering? Try **reducing** the interval gap to say 10 milliseconds or even less. It could be a "hertz" problem - i.e. the animation rate, vs your screen refresh rate, vs your eye's sampling rate.

Comment: it definitely flickering. "hertz problem" is there too, but on my computer every ~2 seconds one frame is dropped. and it looks ugly. and the problem is cross-browser and it is not because of overloaded computer.

Comment: If you change it to `var text = $("#hello").css({background: 'blue', color: 'white'});` the pulsation is more noticeable. Seems like you need to implement some kind of buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <marquee scrolldelay="5" scrollamount="50">
   This is a very fast scrolling text. Try me</marquee>
```

Comment: but so awesome! also 'deprecated'

Comment: It is deprecated by is supported by all browsers... so :)